# PDI XSL transformation Failed : Failed to compile stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, pdi

I want to convert XML to HTML and sending this html by emil. 
I m using XSL transformation  to pass xml to html but it seems I get one problem wiht xsl files 
This is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Reports>
   <Report><PRODUCT>googleDFD </PRODUCT> </Report>
   <Report><PRODUCT>dm.scores_url</PRODUCT> </Report>
   <Report><PRODUCT>dm.scores_url</PRODUCT> </Report>
</Reports>
```

and my xsl file looks like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/Reports">
  <html>
    <head>
     <title>REPORTS</title>
      <style>
        table{
        width:40%;
         }
         table, th ,td{
          padding: 5px;
          text-align: left;
         }
      </style>
     </head>
  <body>
    <h1>REPORT</h1>
    <table>
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
          <td>Reports</td>
      </tr>
    <td>
         <xsl:apply-templates select ="Report">
        </xsl:apply-template>
    </td> 
    </table>
 </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match ="Report">
  <tr>
       <td><xsl:value-of select="PRODUCT"/></td>

  </tr>
 </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when I run the job to convert this xml file to html I got this error 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fEwn.png)

Comment: I got this error
xml to html -  Error : Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected

Comment: Please copy/paste full error *text* into the body of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct

```
<xsl:apply-templates select ="Report">
        </xsl:apply-template>
```

to

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Report"/>
```